# Pretty print graphs?

Tags: akka-stream

I was wondering if there is a preferred way to print a nice visual representation of a Graph, like the one [seen here](https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/current/scala/stream/stream-graphs.html):

```
       +------+
 In1 ~>|      |~> Out1
       | bidi |
Out2 <~|      |<~ In2
       +------+
```